# EF Core (CLI tools 5.0.10) : The snapshot class gets generated under its namespace and outputdir gets ignored

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Try this :

1. In your favorite work folder, create a solution. It will contain a src subfolder, which in turn will contain the following two projects :
2. In src/MainProject create the simplest  .Net Core 5.0 console project. It will act as the domain and the infrastructure for your EF project. You should have the simplest Entity class (just one is enough) and the simplest DbContext class there.
3. In src/MyMigrations create a library project named "MyMigrations" and add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design as a package
4. **Make sure you follow the steps described here (link below)** to make "MyMigrations" the project where you'll manage the migrations (as opposed to the project containing the DbContext)

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

That's where trouble begins.
From the root folder of the solution, create your very first migration :

```
   dotnet ef migrations add Initial --project .\src\MainProject --startup-project .\src\MyMigrations --output-dir ..\MyMigrations\Migrations --namespace Mycompany.MyMigrations.Migrations
```

Not super important, but notice how --output-dir path starts with .. because it starts from --project, which is src/MainProject

Now notice how the Migration file got created in src/MyMigrations/Migrations (correct), but the snapshot file got created in src/MainProject/MyCompany/MyMigrations/Migrations (weird!). **It appears the snapshot file's path is its namespace.**

Well fear not, we keep following the guidelines from the hyperlink above, and we move the snapshot file to the Migrations folder in MyMigrations.

We change a tiny thing in the Entity file, to have something to feed to a new migration.

Create that new migration with almost the same command as above :

```
   dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration --project .\src\MainProject --startup-project .\src\MyMigrations --output-dir ..\MyMigrations\Migrations --namespace Mycompany.MyMigrations.Migrations
```

**Terrible result :**

- the new snapshot file didn't replace the previous one
- Instead it got recreated (brand new) in a folder corresponding to its namespace again -- not the path provided in output-dir

**Everything I've read says that EF should be smart enough to know the snapshot's path, at least  after the Initial migration.** But it doesn't and it creates it in an unwanted folder.

**Is this a bug? If not, how do I manage the path to my snapshot???**

Answer (score 0):

you need change your entered code according this

```
dotnet ef migrations add NewMigration --project .\src\MyMigrations --startup-project .\src\MainProject --output-dir ..\MyMigrations\Migrations --namespace Mycompany.MyMigrations.Migrations
```

in --project argument you have to enter your project that you want migrations created in it.